# Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot where two graph types overlap. Individually they appear as they should but when I'm trying to plot them together the error I'm receiving is "Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'". Any idea how I can solve this?

Following is my code.

```
pq <- ggplot() + 
  geom_density(
    data = bg, 
    aes(x = ideology, fill = type, group = type), 
    alpha = 0.25, 
    color = NA) + 
  geom_vline(
    data = avg_ideology, 
    aes(xintercept = name, color = avg_ideology$type), 
    size = 1, 
    alpha = 0.25) +
  annotate(
    "text", 
    x = avg_ideology$name, 
    label = avg_ideology$label, 
    y = avg_ideology$height, 
    colour = "black", 
    angle = 90, 
    vjust = -0.5, 
    size = 3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(Democrat = "blue", Republican = "red", Z = "black")) +
  labs(
    x = "Position on latent ideological scale", 
    title = "Twitter ideology scores of potential Deomcratic and Republican presidential primary candidates") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
    legend.position = "none", 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.line.y = element_blank()) +
  xlim(-2, 2) +
geom_pointrange(
  data = ideology, 
    aes(x = twscore, y = rown1, color = party), 
    xmin = ideology$lower, 
    xmax = ideology$upper) + 
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("blue", "red", "black")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none", 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.line.y = element_blank()) +
  annotate(
    "text", 
    x= ideology$twscore+0.5, 
    y= ideology$rown1, 
    label= ideology$screen_name, 
    angle=90,
    aes(color= ideology$party)) 
   
pq
```

I want the graph to appear as follows[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid without any data to run your code it's impossible to figure out what's the issue and which line of code produces the error. Hence I would suggest to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Also. Instead of trying to create this kind of plot via one ggplot I would suggest to have a look at [patchwork::inset_element](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/reference/inset_element.html) which would allow to create separate plots and overlay them.